# reading a variable in awk from the command line after entering the command

Tags: awk

I try searching a file by using awk. How can I ask awk to read a variable from the command line as a name to get searched in the file:

this is a regular way I use to search the file and I can ask the user to enter a name to search in the file.txt

```
awk -f myAwk.awk file.txt
```

How can I manage it like this :

```
awk -f myAwk.awk file.txt nameToSearch
```

How can I use ARGC and ARGV to search the nameToSearch in the file.txt?

Comment: You can also search for string inside your awk..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is

```
awk [-W option] [-F value] [-v var=value] [--] 'program text' [file ...]
```

so

```
awk -v MYVAR=nameToSearch -v OTHERVAR=somethingElse -f myAwk.awk file.txt
```

Is that it? of course order of switches ( -f, -v ) does not matter. Obvously you then need to include MYVAR ( OTHERVAR ) for a variable identifier inside awk program itself.

Comment: Note that `-v` is not necessary.  `awk -f myAwk.awk MYVAR=nameToSearch file.txt` works as well.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, you're right but if one uses that method, then do note that it's essential for `MYVAR=...` come after the awk program text or the `-f myAwk.awk`. Also, there are some corner cases where `-v MYVAR=...` will behave better, and awk guides generally recommend using this method over the older method you describe.

Answer (score 1):

To pass a variable to awk, you can use the `-v` command.
For example:

```
cat file.txt | awk -v p="stringToSearch" '$0 ~ p'
```

In this command, tou replace stringToSearch with a pattern (please keep the double quote, they are useful for preserving spaces). The awk command `$0 ~ p` compares the current line to the given pattern.

Another approach is to build the awk command from the shell:

```
p="stringToSearch"
awk "/$p/" file.txt
```

You must use double quotes in the command to force expanding `$p`.

Comment: Never do the second thing above as it can produce very cryptic results based on the value of the shell variable and introduces horrendous escaping requirements to the rest of your script.

Comment: It should not go wrong if you know what value you gave to p. Of course, if you read p from a non controlled source, or let a foreign script control its value, you can have unexpected result. Like with any code.

Comment: Even when you know what value your variable has it introduces the need to escape quotes, backslashes, etc. If you ARE going to use this type of jumping-back-into-shell approach the better syntax would be awk '/'"$p"'/' to avoid the escaping issues but in the end it's just never necessary and a bad habit to get into and when it does fail it can produce VERY cryptic failures and/or error messages. Simply use -v var=value as you show in your first example and you won't get any surprises in future.

Comment: Oh, and just be aware that what the first example is doing is using a string in an RE context which would require escaping of any RE metacharacters and backslashes in "p". If you really want to just check for a string being present in your input record (as opposed to your input record matching an RE) then you should use "index($0,p)" rather than "$0 ~ p".

Answer (score 1):

If it's permitted to change the order of arguments, so that we can do this:

```
awk -f myAwk.awk nameToSearch file.txt
```

then you can do:

```
awk 'NR==1 { nameToSearch = $0; next} { ... rest of myAwk.awk here ...}' nameToSearch file.txt
```

You can of course add the `NR==1 {...}` block to the beginning of your `myAwk.awk` file, then continue using:

```
awk -f myAwk.awk nameToSearch file.txt
```

The technique Piotr Wadas describes has the same effect:

```
awk -v nameToSearch=whatever -f myAwk.awk file.txt
```

and that's what I'd use myself, rather than passing `whatever` as an additional argument to the script. Passing `whatever` as an additional argument is what scripters had to do before the `-v` facilities were added to awk. If writing `-v nameToSearch=` is too verbose, then I'd wrap the whole thing up in a shell script, and say:

```
myShellScript whatever file.txt
```

But you asked how to do it by passing `whatever` as an additional argument to the awk script, so that's what I demonstrated.